# Test Runner can't find .net core sdk

Tags: .net-core

I have just tried to run some test (that are not new) and the test runner is ginving me the following error:

> Testhost process exited with error: It was not possible to find any
>   compatible framework version
>       The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.2.0' was not found.
>         - The following frameworks were found:
>             3.1.0 at [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>       You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.
>       The specified framework can be found at:
>         - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=2.2.0&arch=x86&rid=win10-x86

However I have all the sdks installed on my machine:

> C: --list-sdks
>   2.1.403 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
>   2.1.801 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
>   2.2.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
>   3.1.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

I have recently updated my version of Visual Studio (today) to 16.4.1 and have only had this issue since then. How do I make my Test Runner find the correct sdks again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to quick off the blocks. Found this answer which solves my issue:

[After updated Visual Studio 2019 to 16.4.0 I can't run tests with target framework 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59246822/after-updated-visual-studio-2019-to-16-4-0-i-cant-run-tests-with-target-framewo/59282608#59282608)